# Are there some programs about inverse Fourier and Laplace transfroms?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, signal-processing, integral-transforms

To be more exact, I have a function F[w_,s_], where $w$ is the Fourier transform of $x$ and $s$ is
the Laplace transform of  $t$.

Now I want to perform the double inverse transforms $s\to t$ and $w\to x$.

Thanks!

**If it is not convenient to share the program, can you help me to perform?** My parameters are

```
t0 = 0.1;
alpha = 1.5;
beta = alpha;
mx = alpha*t0/(alpha - 1);
a = 1;
\[Sigma] = 1;
balpha = t0^alpha*Abs[Gamma[1 - alpha]];
```

My function is

```
F[w_,s_]:= (1/(s + (I*a*w)/mx + ((\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)/(2*mx) + 
 balpha/mx^2*s^(alpha - 1)*(I*w*a + 1/2*(\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)))
```

I want to get F[x,t] in real space with $t=1000$, where $x$ is rang from 1500 to 4500.

Thanks!

PS: Here I added a figure, I have tried some programs. The red solid line is the theory I expected and the other lines are obtained from numerical inverse transforms.
[image]

Comment: You define `tt`, but don't use it.

Comment: @user64494 Please ignore it since the above are the total parameters. So some formulas may do not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

First, your `F[w_,s_]:= (1/(s + (I*a*w)/mx + ((\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)/(2*mx) +  balpha/mx^2*s^(alpha - 1)*(I*w*a + 1/2*(\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)))` is a complex valued function. I don't see any reason why its inverse Fourier transform should be a real valued function.

Second, up to the definition used by Mathematica, its inverse Fourier transform
equals

```
Integrate[(1/(s + (I*a*w)/mx + ((\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)/(2*mx) + 
  balpha/mx^2*s^(alpha - 1)*(I*w*a + 1/2*(\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)))*
  Exp[-I*x*w - I*s*t], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, {s, -Infinity,  Infinity}]/(2*Pi)
```

I have doubts whether the above double improper integral can be expressed in closed form. The one can be calculated numerically for $t=1000$ as

```
t0 = 1/10;alpha = 3/2;beta = alpha;mx = alpha*t0/(alpha - 1);a = 1;\[Sigma] = 1;
balpha = t0^alpha*RealAbs[Gamma[1 - alpha]];
f[x_] := NIntegrate[(1/(s + (I*a*w)/
     mx + ((\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)/(2*mx) + 
    balpha/mx^2*
     s^(alpha - 1)*(I*w*a + 1/2*(\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)))*
Exp[-I*x*w - I*s*1000], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, {s, -Infinity, 
Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5,  WorkingPrecision -> 15]/(2*Pi)
f[3600] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1874.91, -0.000207174182415258 - 0.000187617006989998 I}*)
```

Third, the integrand is very oscillating in both variables. I don't know good numeric methods to calculate such sort integrals. Asymptotic methods are known to this end (see M. Fedoryuk. The saddle-point method. Moskva: ”Nauka”. 368 p.  (1977) (in Russian) https://zbmath.org/?q=ai%3Afedoryuk.mikhail-v+py%3A1977 ).

Comment: I'd like to add that `F[w,s]` has an integrable singularity at the origin in view of `Simplify[ComplexExpand[
  Abs[(1/(s + (I*a*w)/mx + ((\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)/(2*mx) + 
       balpha/mx^2*
        s^(alpha - 1)*(I*w*a + 1/2*(\[Sigma]^2 + a^2)*w^2)))]], 
 Assumptions -> s < 0 && w > 0]` which results in $$\frac{9}{\sqrt{-4 s w \left(9 \sqrt{10 \pi } \sqrt[4]{s^2}+10 \pi  w^3+5 (2 \pi -27) w\right)+81 s^2+900 \left(w^4+w^2\right)}} $$ and similar expansions in other quadrants.

Comment: The addition of the `Exclusions -> {{s, w} == {0, 0}}` option changes nothing but time:  now`f[3600] // AbsoluteTiming` produces `{9986.51, -0.000207174182415258 - 0.000187617006989998 I}`.

Comment: thanks!       Usuaslly it is not easy to solve such a problem.